# unable to read CDATA in XML

Tags: java, xml, cdata, dom4j

I'm not able to read CDATA content with DOM4j library

```
<notes>

<note>
<![CDATA[
    something
]]>
</note>
```

I'm trying something like:

```
if(element.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("notes")){
                List notes = element.elements();
                for (int inotes = 0; inotes<notes.size(); inotes++) {
                    String content = ""; // ??????
                }
            }
```

Comment: CDATA is handled by the XML parser.  Just pick out the content of the <note> element.

Answer (score 0):

You get CDATA content by getStringValue

If you have just one note element:

```
String xml="<notes>\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "<note>\r\n" + 
        "<![CDATA[\r\n" + 
        "qslkdfjqoisdèufç_rkjsdqfmlq_zds"+
        "_èçé\"hc<<op<àç\">>>x>pciu\"éêù!x;%xkm<qknc"+
        "    something\r\n" + 
        "]]>\r\n" + 
        "</note></notes>";

// STRING => DOCUMENT
Document docu=DocumentHelper.parseText(xml);

// SELECT UNIQUE 
Node nd=docu.selectSingleNode("//note");

// CONTENT
String value=nd.getStringValue();
System.out.println("VALUE="+value);
```

if you have multiple note tags, use:

```
List<Node> notes = docu.selectNodes( "//note", "." ,true);
for (Node nd: notes)
    {
```